# The Laplacian eigenfunction problem in 1D

Tags: analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to find a twice continuously differentiable $2\pi$-periodic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $f''(x)=\lambda f(x)$. It is easy to see that the Fourier basis functions $\{e_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ are solutions to this problem, but how could I show that there are no solutions to the problem that are not finite linear combinations of the Fourier basis? What are the allowed linear combinations and the allowed eigenvalues $\lambda$ in this case? Any ideas how to reason about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $(e_k(x))'' = -k^2 e_k(x)$, so $\{-k^2\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ are eigenvalues. Notice that $e_k$ and $e_{-k}$ correspond to the same eigenvalue, so any linear combination of these is also an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $-k^2$. Any linear combination of basis elements other than these combinations will not result in an eigenfunction.

No solutions outside this Fourier basis are viable, as the solution to $f'' = \mu f$ is $f(x) = \alpha e^{\sqrt{\mu} x} + \beta e^{-\sqrt{\mu} x}$ and $f(x) = \alpha x + \beta$ when $\mu = 0$. These can only satisfy the periodicity conditions when $\mu = -k^2$ and $f(x) = \alpha e^{ikx} + \beta e^{-ikx}$, which is exactly the Fourier basis.